error when trying to display a multipolygon in react with leaflet
I have the following function
// Función para unir los polígonos superpuestos
export const unifyPolygons = (zones: Zone[]) => {
  const turfPolygons = zones.map(zone =>
    turf.polygon([zone.coordinatesrestriction.map(coord => [coord.lng, coord.lat])])
  );
  // Convertir POLYGON_ENVIGADO a Feature<GeoJsonPolygon>
  const containerPolygon: Feature<GeoJsonPolygon, GeoJsonProperties> = turf.polygon([POLYGON_ENVIGADO]);

  // Convertir turfPolygons a Features<GeoJsonPolygon>
  const turfPolyFeatures: Feature<GeoJsonPolygon, GeoJsonProperties>[] = turfPolygons.map(polygon =>
    turf.polygon(polygon.geometry.coordinates)
  );

  // console.log(  turfPolyFeatures  );
  // Crear un MultiPolygon con el contenedor y los polígonos adicionales
  const allPolygons: Feature<GeoJsonMultiPolygon, GeoJsonProperties> = turf.multiPolygon([
    containerPolygon.geometry.coordinates,
    ...turfPolyFeatures.map(feature => feature.geometry.coordinates)
  ]);
  for (let i = 1; i < turfPolygons.length; i++) {


    }  
  console.log(  allPolygons  );
  
  let unifiedPolygon: number[][] = [];

  // Si es MultiPolygon, obtener las coordenadas del primer polígono
  if (allPolygons.geometry.type === 'MultiPolygon') {
    unifiedPolygon = allPolygons.geometry.coordinates[0][0].map(coord => [coord[1], coord[0]] as [number, number]);
  }

  return unifiedPolygon;
};

and when I try to draw it with the following code it gives me error
{unifiedPolygon.length > 0 && (
        <Polygon positions={unifiedPolygon} className='unified-zone' />
      )}

The error is the following
Type 'number[][]' is not assignable to type 'LatLngExpression[] | LatLngExpression[][] | LatLngExpression[][][]'.
  Type 'number[][]' is not assignable to type 'LatLngExpression[]'.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'LatLngExpression'.
      Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'LatLngTuple'.
        Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)
Polygon.d.ts(6, 5): The expected type comes from property 'positions' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PolygonProps & RefAttributes<Polygon<any>>'

I tried using the "Turf" library but it always generated an error when generating the multipolygon, and now it is generated but it does not print it correctly.
